# Make Docker for mac listen on a tcp port

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to get docker-java (https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) to work with Docker for mac (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/).

How can I set the equivalent of:

`DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"`

On the mac version of Docker?

Answer (score 17):

There is a related answer which suggests a workaround using `socat`.

It does indeed work to expose port 2375 on the network:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Reference:
[Access Docker daemon Remote api on Docker for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411126/access-docker-daemon-remote-api-on-docker-for-mac)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the last docker for mac beta, according to [issue 25064](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25064):

> `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux` is a git database.

Note: if `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database/` does not contain `com.docker.driver.amd64-linux`, go to that `database/` folder, and do a `git reset --hard`.

> The daemon configuration is under `etc/docker/daemon.json`, which just uses the config from the [Linux configuration file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#/linux-configuration-file).
>
> You need to change the config and then do a `git commit`: docker should restart automatically at that point (if not, restart it) with the new configuration.

---

As mentioned by the [OP Michael Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557452/michael-nelson) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262343/make-docker-for-mac-listen-on-a-tcp-port/39264037#comment65868010_39264037), and detailed in "[Docker for Windows](http://docker-saigon.github.io/post/Docker-Beta/)" (which has sections relevant for "Docker for Mac")

> The [VM (Alpine-based)](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/) uses [OpenRC as its init system](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_Init_System).
>
> The Docker `init` script relies on a `/usr/bin/mobyconfig` script.
>   This `mobyconfig` script requires the kernel to boot with a `com.docker.database` label specifying the location of the config file or it bails.
>
> The `mobyconfig` script is able to retrieve `network` and `insecure-registry` configuration for the Docker daemon or pick up a config file from `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

Comment: wow.. this impressively convoluted. These files aren't read directly after that git magic. They have another magic `mobyconfig` utility that reads config from `/Database/branch/master/ro/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux` where the files magically turns up in the VM and then the util recreates the real config files during startup :0

Comment: This is all correct, but if I put any value into the hosts field of daemon.json then Docker refuses to start. I tried many combinations of ["unix:///var/run/docker.socket", "127.0.0.1", "fd://"] all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you don't have a machine running.

```
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

If the output is stating that no default machine, then execute,

```
docker-machine create default --driver virtualbox
```

This will create a default machine and the connection will be successful.

Answer (score -3):

$ docker info

HTTP Proxy: docker.for.mac.http.internal:3128

HTTPS Proxy: docker.for.mac.http.internal:3129

Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/

Hope this helps